# Small chart (1621 length) already getting unresponsive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to draw some charts in my Electron app.

With a small array with length of 1621 the app already gets somewhat unresponsive, and if I draw 2 more series in the same canvas it gets a lot unresponsive.

Using the Chrome developer tools I can see that 1 Chart is occupying 6.6Mb. Is this normal?
Also, I see a lot of drawn things that I don't use like 2542 Objects of type `d3_geom_voronoiEdge`, 1320 Objects of type `d3_geom_voronoiCircle`, 8968 Objects of type `d3_geom_voronoiBeach`,  3509 entries on the DOM Tree (shouldn't I have ~1621 entries? ) and 3247 Objects of type `SVGPathElement`.

My data type is like: `["0","10.2"]`. Already tried parsing to float and the unresponsiveness is maintained.

Also, a lot of `cannot read property of "x"` errors occur.

My code:

```
this.optionsEx` = {
        chart: {
            type: "lineChart",
            x: function(d){return d[0];},
            y: function(d){return d[1];},
            useInteractiveGuideline: false,
            xDomain: null,
            clipVoronoi: false,
            xAxis: {
                axisLabel: "Time(s)",
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(",.1f")(d);
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                axisLabel: "Y Axis",
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(",.2f")(d);
                },
            },
            zoom: {
                enabled: true,
                useFixedDomain: true,
                useNiceScale: false,
                horizontalOff: false,
                verticalOff: true,
                unzoomEventType: "dblclick.zoom"
            }
        }
    };
```

Link to example of unresponsiveness: http://plnkr.co/edit/D4cTD6e4c1ejLuYSee6e?p=preview

The `d3_geom_voronoiCircle` and `d3_geom_voronoiBeach` objects don't seem to appear in plunker, don't know why.

Comment: Couple notes, first, on your error, what's **a lot**?  Spitting tons of error message to the console is slow.  Second, is your chart interactive?  I believe `nvd3` uses voronois for mouse to closest point determination. Third, 1621 points isn't so small and `nvd3` doesn't handle it well.  If your chart is 600px wide, it'll add 3 circles for every pixel in the x direction...

Comment: Essentially, nvd3 provides a lot of functionality and pretty.  You are paying the price for that.

Comment: Ty for the answers. So, give me your advice. Don't use nvd3 and just d3 or highcharts?

Comment: Well, I am biased because I love all things `d3`, so yes my recommendation is always straight `d3`.  I'd target version 4 and probably implement it to draw on a canvas instead of `svg`.

Comment: Ty for the suggestion. I'm going to try that and check if the unresponsiveness is maintained.

Comment: @Mark If you use my example and fork it to use only d3,and the unresponsiveness is a little bit better I will gladly give you the solution.